# Any way to block out new code for legacy versions of CF

Tags: coldfusion

I have written a library I include for some security patches. In that library there are a number of CF8 and up function,attributes,etc.

I really really dont want to cut the functionality down bc adobe couldnt get it together and get this basic functionality into CF7 so Im looking to write separate lines into each function. The issue is when CF is initially reading the code it bugs out if it finds something it doesnt recognize, whether or not it is going to be called.

For example in cfdirectory CF7 doesnt support the 'type' attribute. I have a find directory function that fails in CF7 when the 'type' attribute is present and taking it out increases the search time by 10x.

```
<cftry> 
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#arguments.start#" name="LOCAL.dirquery" type="dir" /><!---//GET QUERY OF DIRECTORIES IN START DIRECTORY--->
<cfcatch>
    <cfsetting requesttimeout="600">
    <cfdirectory action="list" directory="#arguments.start#" name="LOCAL.dirquery" /><!---//GET QUERY OF DIRECTORIES IN START DIRECTORY--->
</cfcatch>
```

This code does not work, neither does a conditional block. Im guessing the reader cannot parse thsi into whatever language and so is failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is probably failing at compile time, not at run time (need to see the error you are receiving to know for sure). If it's a compiler error, you'll need to have break out your CF7 functions in separate components from your CF8+ functions. Then check the CF version at run time to determine which component/function to call.

Here's some pseudo code you can use in application startup to load the correct version functions into memory. That way you have a consistent interface for calling the functions anywhere in your code.

Pseudo Code:

```
onApplicationStart(){

    if (server.coldfusion.productversion == 7){
        application.cffunctions = CF7FunctionsComponent;
    } else {
        application.cffunctions = CF8FunctionsComponent;
    }

}
```

Everywhere else, you call the same function regardless of CF version currently running:

```
application.cffunctions.doSomething();
```

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. I made a legacy version of the code and am using separate includes now I was just trying to avoid that to keep the code clean.

Comment: Depending on how your app is architected, you can load all your version-specific components into memory at application startup. That way you won't have to use this version-checking logic every time you want to use the functions.

Comment: Please see my edited answer for clarification of how you can keep your code clean.

Comment: `<cfinclude>` would also work for the solution illustrated above in CFML

Comment: `<cfinclude>` would only work if `onRequest()` method is used in Application.cfc. When `onRequest()` is used, all functions in Application.cfc become available to every CFM page request within the application. In that way all functions defined in the `<cfinclude>` would become members of Application.cfc itself, and thus available on every request throughout the application.